# With the goal of having a function defined for all values of x, why can you only sometimes simplify a fraction, making divisor not equal zero?

Tags: functions, polynomials, fractions, irreducible-polynomials

The function $$ f(x) = \frac{x^2-1}{x-1} $$ is not defined at *x = 1*. Even if I simplify the function, I need to keep in mind where I've came from:
$$f(x) = x + 1 , x \neq 1$$
But if the original function looks like *f(x) = x + 1*, then there is no problem if I first expand the fraction so that *x - 1* is divisor, and then again simplifying the divisor away.

Why is there a difference?

The function $$g(x) = \frac{\sqrt{x}-3}{x-9}$$ is defined for *x = 9* because you **can** simplify the function; *g(9) = 1/6*. I get that *(x - 1)* is here the last factor with *x* in it, but I don't see why that should mean we treat the functions differently, as to their defined domain of x values.

Would anyone care to explain this to me?

Comment: What do you mean by "treating" them differently?

Comment: $g(x)$ is not defined for $x=9$.  You can perform operations to it so as to rewrite it in a different _form_ (I guess?) and then define it as a different function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f(x)=\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}$ is not defined at $1$ since $\frac00$ is not defined. Thus we assume the domain of $f$ is $\Bbb R\setminus\{1\}$. The domain of the function is part of the function's definition, and never changes. Even if you simplify $f(x)=x+1$, that statement is still only true on the domain of $f$, which is $\Bbb R\setminus\{1\}$.

The function $h(x)=x+1$ is defined on all $\Bbb R$, so we assume this is the domain of $h$. The statement $h(x)=\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}$ is true whenever $x\neq 1$, but it is *not* true when $x=1$. Now the fact that $h(x)=\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}$ when $x\neq 1$ by itself does *not* imply $h(1)=2$. However, this is true regardless, since we begin with the definition $h(x)=x+1$.

The function $g(x)=\frac{\sqrt x-3}{x-9}$ has domain $\Bbb R\setminus \{9\}$. It is also true that $g(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt x+3}$ whenever $x\neq 9$, but this doesn't change the fact that $9$ is not in the domain of $g$.

---

Really, we should acknowledge that "functions" are usually not defined rigorously in lower level math classes. This is mostly just to avoid confusion, since people already have a hard time understanding functions. Formally, a function $f$ is the data of

- a set $D$ called the domain of $f$
- a set $C$ called the co-domain of $f$
- a "rule" which gives you exactly one value $f(x)\in C$  for each $x\in D$.

If a function is only defined with the equation $f(x)=\frac{1}{x-1}$, for example, then we make some reasonable assumptions about what $D$ and $C$ are. We can assume $C=\Bbb R \setminus \{0\}$, and assume that $D\subset \Bbb R$ is the set of all $x$ for which the equation $f(x)=\frac{1}{x-1}$ is defined.